# How to integrate flutter web build inside react app for specific route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter, single-page-application, micro-frontend

I have a requirement where i want to run flutter app for specific URL inside react application and for rest of the urls, react app will run.

I will have flutter build folder and also will use browser's communication channel to pass data but is there any way how i can integrate flutter app inside react app with this page?

Comment: How do you serve your react application? Do you use Nginx, Apache? You could edit your config file to serve the flutter app on that specific URL. Tell me if you want me to answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: ACtually the thing is i want to integrate flutter build inside react application because in real time i would like to data transfer. I will need data stored by react application inside flutter app so i can't do it with nginx or apache.

The only solution i can think of is Micro-frontends but couldn't find any blog or solution regarding this.

However we are using nginx with pm2

Comment: try hosting flutter webapp, and then in react app load it inside `iframe`. Just thoughts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found one solution which can help to integrate flutter app build in react app.
Just put your flutter app build inside /public folder. And inside route component's on load event, load that application with below code.

```
function loadMainDartJs() {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = './main.dart.js';
    scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
    document.getElementById('flutterPreview').append(scriptTag);
}
loadMainDartJs();
```

Comment: Hi ravi, could you please eleborate your answer a little more? My users log in using the react web site: mysite.com/auth and once logged in, I want to take them to the Flutter web app in mysite.com/profile and I want to pass the authentication data to Flutter.

Answer (score 3):

**And also in Next.js**

all you need is import your script in Head tag in page that you need, for example:

`/pages/index.jsx`

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <script src='/main.dart.js' defer></script>
      </Head>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and your dart script move to public folder:
`/public/main.dart.js`

updated: in the Next.js 14 (app dir)

```
'use client'
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Script from "next/script";


function Page() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Script
                src="/main.dart.js"
                strategy="lazyOnload"
            />
            {/*  other codes  */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Page), {
    ssr: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Flutter's Embedding a Flutter App](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#embedding-a-flutter-app-into-an-html-page) you can utilize some JS to bootstrap the flutter app. This works great if your Flutter Web app is already hosted elsewhere.

### Embedding a Flutter app into an HTML Page with Javascript

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Ensure your flutter target is present on the page... -->
    <div id="flutter_host">Loading...</div>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          onEntrypointLoaded: async function(engineInitializer) {
            let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
              // Pass a reference to "div#flutter_host" into the Flutter engine.
              hostElement: document.querySelector("#flutter_host")
            });
            await appRunner.runApp();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Iframe Embed

Unfortunately for us we need a specific web route loaded for Flutter Web which this does not seem to handle. So we went with the other option they mention which is to utilize an `iframe` element. This allowed us to point to a specific Flutter Web route and load up the associated Flutter web page.

There must be a way to specify a route with the JS bootstrapping, but I couldn't find anything explicit on their documentation. Hopefully they handle this in the future.

```html
<iframe src="https://flutterWeb.url/some/path"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -3):

blog.logrocket.com/flutter-web-app-node-js Please go through this URL. (Courtesy: blog.logrocket.com and stackoverflow)

Comment: Your solution is completely different for what i was asking. This blog no way renders flutter app build inside react application.